# Group by and count with R

Tags: r

I have a table in R that kinda looks like this:

| DoctorID | Region |
| AHDCBA   | 4 15   |
| ABHAHF   | 1 8 T4 |
.
.
.
. and so on. Both columns are character types. I want to know how many doctors are there in each region. I tried this code but it's giving me errors. If anyone could help me i'd really appreciate it.

```
doctors_region <- doctors %>%
 group_by(Region, DoctorID)%>%
 summarise(number = n())

doctors_region
```

Comment: I tried to edit your table but I couldn't make it into a valid table. Can you please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data with `dput(head(doctors_region))`? The code looks OK if the data is in the correct format so I suspect it isn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `count()` instead, e.g.

```r
doctors_region <- doctors %>%
 group_by(Region, DoctorID)%>%
 count()
```

I don't have your data, so here is an example using `mtcars`

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am, gear) %>% 
  count()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   am, gear [4]
#>      am  gear     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0     3    15
#> 2     0     4     4
#> 3     1     4     8
#> 4     1     5     5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here is the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html), which also has more examples.

Comment: Or even `mtcars %>% count(am, gear)`. Though the output is not a tibble.

Comment: True, and a good remark! I  wanted to showcase the `group_by`, as the original question used it.